# Mapeamento mais adequado de JSON para objeto Java

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos

Preciso trabalhar com um JSON que tem informações de receitas. Este JSON possui um objeto (Recipe) com alguns arrays de objetos (ingredients, steps).

O que seria mais adequado, do ponto de vista da orientação a objetos: criar 3 classes-- `Recipes`, `Ingredients`, `Steps`-- com os atributos recebidos pelo JSON (id, name para a classe Recipes, quantity, measure, ingredient para a classe Ingredients, etc...) ou criar uma única classe (Recipes) com os atributos dela (id, name) e dois `ArrayList` de `HashMap` com os valores de Ingredients e Steps? E por quê?

Screenshot do json (não aparece o array Steps).
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não use screenshots no lugar de código, por favor. Isso atrapalha a busca e atrapalha a leitura por usuários de leitores de tela.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usar *maps* quando a chave é sempre a mesma (sempre `id`, `name`, `ingredients`) não faz muito sentido. O ideal, do ponto de vista de deixar o seu código mais expressivo, é ter uma classe pra cada conceito que se repete. O problema é que, quando a gente trabalha com JSON, essas classes explodem em quantidade. O que a gente faz é usar alguma biblioteca que cria esse mapeamento para a gente e alguma ferramenta que gera as classes automaticamente baseado no JSON.

Experimente o [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) ou o [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) para o mapeamento e o [jsonschema2pojo.org](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) para gerar as classes pra você.